# Gradle's central declaration for plugins block?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, toml

Latest Gradle version, 7.0, [introduced](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:central-declaration-of-dependencies) a feature of central declaration of dependencies. You can now declare your dependencies (versions, libraries or even sets of related libraries - bundles) in a separate file and use them across whole, even multi-module, project:

```
# libs.versions.toml

[versions]
kotlin = "1.4.32"
tgbotapi = "0.33.3"

[libraries]
tgbotapi-core = { group = "dev.inmo", name = "tgbotapi.core", version.ref = "tgbotapi" }

[bundles]
tgbotapi = ["tgbotapi-core"]
```

```kotlin
// And then in your build.gradle.kts
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.bundles.tgbotapi)
}
```

However, I cannot make this feature work with the `plugins` block:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm").version(libs.versions.kotlin).apply(false) // Unresolved reference: libs
}
```

How do i use this central declaration for plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.your.library) apply false
}
```

to add plugins. Your Kotlin version notation should also work though.
You could also add this to your libs.versions.toml:

```
[plugins]
kotlin-jvm = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm", version.ref = "kotlin" }
```

and then:

```
plugins {
     alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.jvm) apply false
}
```